# Non-fractional digits impact on double-precision numbers

Tags: c++, double

Consider these two numbers :

```
double v1 = 2433.36.. 
double v2 = 0.36...
```

`v2` might be more precise ( more accurate digits after the decimal point ) due to the fact that less digits are used for encoding the left part of the radix point or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By precision you clearly mean accurate digits after the decimal point. Then the answer is yes. Floating point numbers have a fixed number of digits. If you have more before the decimal point then you can have fewer after the decimal point (or radix point). And leading or trailing zeros don't count in this calculation.

Comment: digits10 show the maximum number of digits of a floating point number ? for double it's equal to 15 that means if a double has 2 digits on the left it can have at maximum 13 digits on the right ?